# How to upload an artifact from gradle into a nexus repository?

Tags: gradle, nexus

I have built an artifact with gradle that I now need to upload to Nexus. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle's [Maven Publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) can be used for that. The documentation is clear enough I think, you will find there examples that you can adapt for uploading to Nexus repositories.